# Finding a matrix from its diagonal and the off-diagonal elements of its inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nonnegative-matrices

This question comes from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/457375/recover-full-covariance-matrix-from-covariance-diagonal-and-precision-off-diagon  where it have not found answers. So, let $\Sigma$ be an $N\times N$ covariance (that is, positive semidefinite) matrix, but we do only know its diagonal and the off-diagonal elements of its inverse $\Sigma^{-1}$ (known as precision matrix).

How can we find $\Sigma$ effectively?

Comment: If it is positive semi definite (and not positive definite) why does it have an inverse?

Comment: @username: That is just the definition of a covariance matrix, but in this case, we certainly must assume it has an inverse.

Comment: the computation is a matter of solving $N$ equations with $N$ unknowns; there are multiple solutions, some experimentation suggests that only a single solution produces a positive definite $\Sigma$; is there a proof for that?

Comment: I raised the issue of the uniqueness of the reconstruction in a separate [thread](https://mathoverflow.net/q/406831/11260)

Answer (score 2):

Following the ideas from my answer to [Carlo's question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406831/uniquely-reconstruct-a-matrix-m-from-its-inverse-m-1-if-n-elements-of?noredirect=1&lq=1), let $M(z_1, \ldots, z_n)$ be the symmetric matrix with $M(z_1, \ldots, z_n)_{ij} = \Sigma_{ij}$ for $i \neq j$ and $M(z_1, \ldots, z_n)_{ii} = z_i$.

Use any sort of numerical optimization algorithm to maximize
$$\log \det M(z_1, \ldots, z_n) - \sum_{i=1}^n \Sigma^{-1}_{ii} z_i$$
on the open set of $(z_1, \ldots, z_n)$ where $M(z_1, \ldots, z_n)$ is positive definite. The function in question is concave, so the optimum is unique and shouldn't be hard to find. This $M(z_1,\ldots, z_n)$ will have the desired property.

The equations one gets seems to have fairly high degree, so I would not attempt a symbolic solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the [linked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/457375/recover-full-covariance-matrix-from-covariance-diagonal-and-precision-off-diagon) the OP also asks for the special case that the off-diagonal elements of $\Sigma^{-1}$ have a rank-one structure, $(\Sigma^{-1})_{ij}=u_i v_j$ for $i\neq j$. In that case the covariance matrix can be reconstructed as follows.

Denote $\Sigma^{-1}=A+uv^\top$, with $u,v$ known rank-$N$ vectors and $A={\rm diag}\,(d_1,d_2,\ldots d_N)$ an unknown diagonal matrix. According to the [Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ then has diagonal elements
$$\Sigma_{ii}= x_i - {x_i^2 u_iv_i \over 1 +\sum_{n=1}^N u_nv_n x_n },\;\;i=1,2,\ldots N,$$
with $\;\;x_n=1/d_n$. These are $N$ equations where the $N$ unknowns $x_n$ appear quadratically.

This method of solution is efficient, but I do not have a proof that the solution with a positive definite $\Sigma$ is unique.