# Uniquely reconstruct a matrix $M$ from its inverse $M^{-1}$ if $n$ elements of $M^{-1}$ are unknown and $n$ elements of $M$ are given

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nonnegative-matrices

This question was motivated by [a recent MO post.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/406753/11260) You know $n$ elements of the $N\times N$ matrix $M$ and you do *not* know $n$ elements of the inverse $M^{-1}$ (but you know the other $N^2-n$ elements of $M^{-1}$). Equating $(M^{-1})^{-1}=M$ gives $n$ nonlinear equations in $n$ unknowns, which in general will have multiple solutions. Under which additional condition can one reconstruct the matrix $M$ uniquely? Does it matter where in the matrix are the $n$ elements located?

**Conjecture:** *A positive definite $N\times N$ matrix is uniquely determined by its diagonal elements and by the off-diagonal elements of its inverse.*

For $N=2$ it is true,$^\ast$ and some experimentation$^{\ast\ast}$ for larger $N$ suggests it is true for all $N$.

---

$^\ast$ For $N=2$ one has $M = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ b & c
\end{pmatrix}$, $M^{-1} = \frac{1}{a c - b^2} \begin{pmatrix}c & -b \\ -b & a
\end{pmatrix}$, we know $a,c$ and we know $\beta=b/(ac−b^2)$. There are two solutions for the unknown $b$, $b_\pm=(\pm\sqrt{4ac\beta^2+1}−1)/2\beta$, only $b_+$ gives a positive definite $M$.

$^{\ast\ast}$ [Mathematica test](https://ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/pdtest.nb) for $N=3,4,5$, when there are, respectively, up to $5,14,22$ solutions for the unknown matrix elements, but only one of these gives a positive definite $M$.

Comment: I hesitated whether to raise this as a follow-up of the cited MO post, but following [this advice](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5150/11260) I ask it separately.

Comment: Over what field are the entries? Are you asking about all fields?

Comment: one can take $M$ real symmetric (in the linked post it is a covariance matrix).

Comment: Perhaps you mean your conjecture to be "$n = N$ elements on the diagonal and $N^2 - n = N^2 - N$ off diagonal elements"? Otherwise already for $N = 2$, giving the two diagonal elements of $M^{-1}$ only determines the off diagonal element of $M$ up to sign.

Comment: Actually, the conjecture is false for $N = 2$.

Comment: it's true for $N=2$, I added the brief calculation for that case.

Comment: Are you claiming that the symmetric case suffices for the general case or that the symmetric case suffices for your purposes?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg -- I have not thought (yet) about the case of a positive definite but non-symmetric matrix; in the context of a covariance matrix we can assume it is both p.d. and symmetric.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense...but when you say "$n$ nonlinear equations in $n$ unknowns", should both instances of $n$ be replaced with $N^2$ (at least in the non-symmetric case)?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg --- I don't think so: take $M^{-1}$, label the $n$ unknowns $x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n$, then invert that matrix to obtain a matrix $\tilde{M}(x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n)$; let the known elements of $M$ be $M_{i_1,j_1}, M_{i_2,j_2}\ldots M_{i_n,j_n}$; then the $n$ equations with $n$ unknowns are $\tilde{M}_{i_k,j_k}(x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n) =M_{i_k,j_k}$, $k=1,2,\ldots n$.

Comment: Okay---I should indeed have realized what you were doing. I preferred to think of the $N^2$ missing variables from the two matrices combined as the variables, and to write the equation $M\times M^{−1}=I$. This gives $N^2$ equations (for the $N^2$ entries) that are at worst quadratic, which seemed easier to think about than fewer equations of higher degree.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The conjecture is true. More precisely, here is what I will prove:

**Theorem** Partition $\{ (i,j) : 1 \leq i \leq j \leq n \}$ into two disjoint sets, $A \sqcup B$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be positive definite $n \times n$ matrices and suppose that $X_{ij} = Y_{ij}$ for $(i,j) \in A$ and $(X^{-1})_{ij} = (Y^{-1})_{ij}$ for $(i,j) \in B$. Then $X = Y$.

**Lemma 1** Consider the function $f(M) = \log \det(M)$ on the space of $n \times n$ matrices $M$ with positive determinant. Then we can think of the gradient, $\nabla(f)$, as an $n \times n$ matrix as well. In this sense, we have $\nabla(f)|_M = (M^{-1})^T$.

**Proof:** Let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix with a $1$ in position $(i,j)$ and $0$'s everywhere else. Then $\nabla(f)_{ij} = \tfrac{d}{dt} \log \det(M+t E_{ij})$. This is $\tfrac{1}{\det(M)} \ \tfrac{d\ \det(M+t E_{ij})}{dt} = \tfrac{1}{\det(M)} \cdot (-1)^{i+j} \det \widehat{M_{ij}}$. Here $\widehat{M}_{ij}$ is the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix where we delete row $i$ and column $j$. Using the formula for the inverse matrix in terms of the adjugate matrix, we see that $\nabla(f)_{ij} = (M^{-1})_{ji}$. $\square$

**Lemma 2** The function $f$ is strictly concave on the cone of positive definite matrices.

**Proof** Let $P$ be a positive definite matrix and let $Q$ be a symmetric matrix. We will show that $f(P+tQ)$ is concave for small $t$.

Since $P$ is positive definite, we can factor $P = ZZ^T$ for some invertible $Z$. Then $\log \det(P+Q t) = \log P + \log \det (\mathrm{Id} + t Z^{-1} Q (Z^{-1})^T)$. Since $Z^{-1} Q (Z^{-1})^T$ is symmetric, it is diagonalizable, say with eigenvalues $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, ..., $\lambda_n$. So $\log \det (\mathrm{Id} + t Z^{-1} Q (Z^{-1})^T) = \sum \log (1+t \lambda_i)$. As long as $|t| < \min(|\lambda_i|^{-1})$, this is a sum of concave functions. $\square$

Now, let $A$, $B$, $X$ and $Y$ be as in the statement of the theorem. Let $V = \mathrm{Span}_{(i,j) \in B} (E_{ij}+E_{ji})$.

The condition that $X_{ij} = Y_{ij}$ for $(i,j) \in A$ means that $Y$ is in
the affine space $X+V$.

From Lemma 1, the condition that $(X^{-1})_{ij} = (Y^{-1})_{ij}$ for $(i,j) \in B$ means that $f$, when restricted to the affine space $X+V$, has the same gradient at $X$ and at $Y$.

Now, the space of positive definite matrices is convex, so its intersection with the affine space $X+V$ is convex, so we can draw a line segment from $X$ to $Y$ and the line segment will stay in the
space of positive definite matrices. By Lemma 2, our function $f$ restricted to this line segment will be strictly concave. But by our observation in the previous paragraph, this function has the same derivative at $X$ and at $Y$. This is only possible if the line segment has length $0$, so $X=Y$. $\square$

---

This was a uniqueness result. I will now prove an existence result. Let $A$ and $B$ be as above, and let $P$ and $Q$ be positive definite matrices. I will now show that there is positive definite matrix $X$ with $X_{ij} = P_{ij}$ for $(i,j) \in A$ and $(X^{-1})_{ij} = Q_{ij}$ for $(i,j) \in B$.

As above, let $V=\mathrm{Span}_{(i,j) \in B} (E_{ij}+E_{ji})$. Let $K$ be the intersection of the affine space $P+V$ with the cone of positive definite matrices. Let $g(X) = \log \det X - \mathrm{Tr}(QX)$. We will show that there is a point $X$ in $K$ where $\nabla(g)=0$. Since $X \in K$, the matrix $X$ is positive definite with $X_{ij} = P_{ij}$ for $(i,j) \in A$. By the computations in the first part, the equation $\nabla(g)=0$ shows that $(X^{-1})_{ij} = Q_{ij}$.

So we are reduced to the goal of showing that $g$ has a local maximum in $K$. Fortunately, $P \in K$, so $K$ is nonempty. Unfortunately, $K$ is not compact. So we need to replace it by a compact version. Let $\overline{K}$ be the set of positive semi-definite matrices in $P+V$. So $\overline{K}$ is closed, but not yet compact.

**Lemma** There is a constant $c>0$ such that, for all positive definite matrices $X$, we have $|X| \leq c \mathrm{Tr}(QX)$, where $|X|$ is the Frobenius norm.

**Proof** The statement of the Lemma is invariant under conjugating $Q$ and $X$ by an orthogonal matrix, so we may assume that $Q$ is diagonal, with diagonal entries $0 < q_1 < q_2 < \cdots < q_n$. So
$$\mathrm{Tr}(QX)= \sum_i q_i X_{ii} \geq q_1 \sum_i X_{ii}.$$
We also have
$$|X| = \sqrt{ \sum_{i,j} X_{ij}^2}  \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} X_{ii} X_{jj}} = \sum_i X_{ii}.$$
(We have used that $X$ is positive definite to deduce the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality $X_{ij}^2 \leq X_{ii} X_{jj}$.) So we can take $c=q_1$. $\square$.

Now, if the eigenvalues of $X$ are $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, \dots, $\lambda_n$, then $\det(X) = \prod \lambda_i$ and $|X| = \sqrt{\sum \lambda_i^2}$ so we have $\det(X) \leq |X|^n$ and thus $\log \det(X) \leq n \log |X| \leq n (\log \mathrm{Tr}(QX)+\log c)$. So $g(X)$ is bounded above by $n \log \mathrm{Tr}(QX) - \mathrm{Tr}(QX) + n \log c$.

We have $\lim_{z \to \infty} n \log z - z=- \infty$ so, if $\mathrm{Tr}(QX) \to \infty$ then $g(X) \to - \infty$. Thus, we can choose some large $M$ such that the value of $g$ at $P$ is larger then its value on the half space $\{ X : \mathrm{Tr}(QX) \geq M \}$.

Now, consider the function $X$ on $\overline{K} \cap \{ X : \mathrm{Tr}(QX) \leq M \}$. This, finally, is a compact set, so $g$ achieves a maximum somewhere on it. The maximum is not at the positive semidefinite points, since $g$ is $-\infty$ there, and it is not on the hyperplane $\{\mathrm{Tr}(QX) = M \}$ by the choice of $M$. So the maximum is in the interior and we win. $\square$

---

UPDATE: I recently talked with Piotr Zwiernik and Thomas Kahle about
this question, and they explained to me that this is a special case of
a 1978 theorem of Barndorff-Nielsen which goes by the name
"Variational Independence". From their perspective, this has nothing
to do with matrices or inverses, it is solely a theorem of convex
analysis. I'll do my best to explain the Variational Independence
theorem. Thanks to Piotr and Thomas for their help; of course, all
errors are mine.

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space, $C$ an open convex subset of $V$ and $f$ a $C^1$ strictly convex function $C \to \mathbb{R}$ with the property that $|\nabla(f)(x)| \to \infty$ as $x$ approaches any point in $\partial C$. Such a pair $(C,f)$ is called "of Legendre type".

In our application, $V$ will be symmetric matrices, $C$ will be positive definite symmetric matrices and $f$ will be $f(X) = - \log \det(X)$, so $\nabla(f)(X) = - X^{-1}$.

Let $V^{\ast}$ be the dual vector space to $V$, so $\nabla(f)$ takes
values in $V^{\ast}$. Let $C^{\ast} = \nabla(f)(C)$. Then $C^{\ast}$
is an open convex set and $\nabla(f): C \to C^{\ast}$ is
bijective. For $x^{\ast} \in C^{\ast}$, define $f^{\ast}(x^{\ast}) =
\min_{x \in C} f(x) - \langle x^{\ast}, x \rangle$; this is known as
the [Legendre conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation#Legendre_transformation_in_more_than_one_dimension) of $f$. Then the pair $(C^{\ast}, f^{\ast})$ is also of Legendre type, and $\nabla(f^{\ast})$ is the inverse bijection $C^{\ast} \to C$. See Chapter 5, Section 26, of [Rockafellar](https://doi.org/10.1515/9781400873173) for the technical details here.

Now, suppose that we have a short exact sequence of vector spaces $0
\to B \overset{\beta}{\longrightarrow} V
\overset{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} A \to 0$, so that we get a dual
sequence $0 \to A^{\ast} \overset{\alpha^{\ast}}{\longrightarrow} V^{\ast}
\overset{\beta^{\ast}}{\longrightarrow} B^{\ast} \to 0$. In our setting; $A$
and $B$ will be the symmetric matrices supported on the coordinates
indexed by the disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ (which is why I reused the
notation), so $\alpha(X)$ and $\beta^{\ast} \nabla(f)(X)$ are the
projections of $X$ and $X^{-1}$ onto the $A$ and $B$ coordinates
respectively.

The "variational independence" theorem is that the map
$$x \mapsto (\alpha(x), \beta^{\ast} \nabla(f)(x))$$
is always a bijection between $C$ and $\alpha(C) \times
\beta(C^{\ast})$.

See Theorem 5.34 in [Barndorff-Nielsen](https://doi.org/10.1002/9781118857281) for the original proof, and see Section 5.1 in [Zwiernik](https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.03590) for a very accessible discussion, including the current application and related transformations.

Comment: I am deeply impressed.

Comment: existence --- uniqueness --- well done, in my world this would be stuff for a publication, but perhaps MO suffices.

Comment: I have been wondering if this is publishable. I agree that the significance is high enough, the problem is originality. I suspect that a natural question like this must have been answered before, but I don't know where to look for it. I'm going to start poking around in the algebraic statistics literature, and then looking for people to ask.

Comment: One of the reasons that MO is more fun than regular research is that, when I solve an interesting question, I am not required to look for previous work before I get credit for it.

Comment: one previous work could be [Positive Definite Completions of Partial Hermitian Matrices](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379584902076)

Comment: Sturmfels and Uhler, "Multivariate Gaussians, semidefinite matrix completion, and convex algebraic geometry" seems very relevant.  https://doi.org/10.1007/s10463-010-0295-4

Comment: If you look at equation (11) in that paper, it is almost the current problem, except that the constraint on the entries of $\Sigma^{-1}$ is that those entries are $0$, rather than being allowed to make them equal any positive definite matrix.

Comment: It looks like there is tons of literature on constraining $(X^{-1})_{ij}=0$ for certain $(i,j)$, the key phrase is "graphical Gaussian model". But I haven't found anything yet on imposing nonzero values.

Comment: I would upvote twice if I could.

Comment: See my answer below, in the form of a comment of Barndorff-Nielsen 's Variational Independence.

Answer (score 5):

Too long for a comment of Barndorff-Nielsen's Variational Independence. It turns out to be important for Continuum Physics, more precisely in Thermodynamics.

One considers a field $(t,x_1,\ldots,x_d)\mapsto u=(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$, taking values in an open convex subset $O$. It is governed by a (first-order PDE) system of conservation laws
$$
\partial_tu+\sum_1^d\partial_{x_\alpha}f^\alpha(u)=0.
$$
A typical example is that of the Euler equations in inviscid gas dynamics, where we neglect heat diffusion. Here $n=d+2$ and the coordinates of $u$ consist in mass density $\rho$, linear momentum $\rho v$ ($v=(v_1,\ldots,v_d)$ is the fluid velocity) and the mechanical energy
$$E=\frac12\rho|v|^2+\rho e.$$
Hereabove, $e$ is the internal energy per unit mass. The PDEs express the local conservation of mass, momentum and energy.

Thermodynamics assumes that such a system is compatible with an additional conservation law
$$\partial_t\eta(u)+{\rm div}_x\vec q(u)=0,$$
where $\eta$ is a strictly convex function, which we call the **entropy** of the system. Mind that physicists prefer a concave entropy; mathematicians' entropy is just the opposite. Actually the compatibility is valid only for Lipschitz continuous fields $u$ (reversible processes), because it involves the chain rule. Irreversible processes are instead constrained by the inequality
$$\partial_t\eta(u)+{\rm div}_x\vec q(u)\le0,$$
understood in the distributional sense.

An important fact is that the existence of such a strictly convex entropy implies that the system of PDEs is **symmetric hyperbolic** in suitable coordinates (Lax & Friedrichs, Godunov), and therefore the Cauchy problem is well-posed, at least locally in time, for suitably regular initial data (Leray, Garding).

Now let us go back to the matter of the MO question. Let us choose some coordinates, say $U:=(u_1,\ldots,u_r)$. We wish to discard the remaining ones $(u_{r+1},\ldots,u_n)$, while freezing the "dual" coordinates
$$
\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial u_{r+1}}=a_{r+1},\ldots,\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial u_n}=a_n,
$$
where $a_{r+1},\ldots,a_n$ are given constants. Because
$$u\mapsto \left(u_1,\ldots,u_r,\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial u_{r+1}},\ldots,\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial u_n}\right)$$
is one-to-one, we may write any function $g(u)$ as $\widetilde{g}(u_1,\ldots,u_r)$ over the level set defined by $\vec a$ .
This allows us to define a so-called **reduced** system
$$
\partial_tU+\sum_1^d\partial_{x_\alpha}F^\alpha(u)=0,
$$
where $F^\alpha_j=\widetilde{f^\alpha_j}$ for $j=1,\ldots,r$. Notice that we retained only the $r$ first lines of the original system.

> Now the Theorem: The reduced system admits too a strictly convex entropy $\eta_*$, obtained in the following way. Consider the Legendre transform $\hat\eta$, which is defined over $\nabla\eta(O)$. Take its restriction to the convex set
> $$\nabla\eta(O)\bigcap\{z\,;\,z_{r+1}=a_{r+1},\ldots,z_n=a_n\}.$$
> Then take back the Legendre transform $\eta_*$ of this restriction, noticing that this is a function of $u_1,\ldots,u_r$.

One consequence of the theorem is that the reduced system is symmetrizable too, hence hyperbolic. The other one is that it gives a procedure to find the entropy of the reduced system.

**Application** to Gas dynamics: here $\eta=-\rho s$ and $s=s(\rho,e)$ is the (physical) entropy per unit mass. The latter satisfies the Gibbs identity
$$\theta ds=de+pd\frac1\rho,$$
$p(\rho,e)$ being the pressure. Let us choose  $r=d+1$, noticing that $r+1=n$ (we discard only one coordinate and one conservation law) and $u_n=E$. One easily checks that
$$\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial E}=-\frac1\theta,$$
so that the reduced system is just isothermal dynamics. Amazingly, the reduced entropy $\eta_*$ is just the mechanical energy !

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks.